Chakra UI Table Pagination Bug
I implemented a table with Chakra UI that works besides for a bug with the pagination. When I click "next" or "previous", it only adds to the list of elements being displayed (instead of replacing it with the "next" or "previous" elements as pagination should).
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Table, Thead, Tbody, Tr, Th, Td, TableContainer, Button, Box } from '@chakra-ui/react';

type EmployeeData = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    occupation: string;
    salary: number;
    duration: string;
};

type EmployeeTableProps = {
    employeeData: EmployeeData[];
};

const EmployeeTable: React.FC<EmployeeTableProps> = ({ employeeData }) => {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
    const rowsPerPage = 10; // You can adjust this number as needed
    const numPages = Math.ceil(employeeData.length / rowsPerPage);

    const currentPageData = employeeData.slice(
        currentPage * rowsPerPage,
        (currentPage + 1) * rowsPerPage
    );

    const nextPage = () => {
        setCurrentPage((current) => Math.min(current + 1, numPages - 1));
    };

    const previousPage = () => {
        setCurrentPage((current) => Math.max(current - 1, 0));
    };

    return (
        <Box>
            <TableContainer
                bg="white"
                border="2px"
                borderRadius="10"
                borderColor="black"
                p="5px 0 5px 0"
            >
                <Table variant='striped' size='sm' colorScheme='purple'>
                    <Thead>
                        <Tr>
                            <Th>Name</Th>
                            <Th>Occupation</Th>
                            <Th>Salary</Th>
                            <Th>Duration</Th>
                        </Tr>
                    </Thead>
                    <Tbody>
                        {currentPageData.map((item) => (
                            <Tr key={item.id}>
                                <Td>{item.name}</Td>
                                <Td>{item.occupation}</Td>
                                <Td>{item.salary}</Td>
                                <Td>{item.duration}</Td>
                            </Tr>
                        ))}
                    </Tbody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
            <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between" mt="4">
                <Button onClick={previousPage} disabled={currentPage === 0}>Previous</Button>
                <Button onClick={nextPage} disabled={currentPage >= numPages - 1}>Next</Button>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    );
};

export default EmployeeTable;


I've console.logged the values that should be displayed at a given time and they are correct, which leads me to believe that it is a problem with the chakra UI components. I've also tried many different versions of this including using state for employeeData, none of which work. Right now the data is imported from a json file in the component that calls this employeeTable component.
